# How to find number of TFS test cases for a given bug with API

Tags: c#, api, tfs

I am trying to use the TFS API to scan through all my bug workitems, and see if there are any with no associated test cases. I was thinking about using `bug.Fields[26].Value == 0` to see how many Related Links there are, but I am not sure if test cases are the only things that are considered related links.

If there are no test cases associated with the bug, I want to create a test case for it. I already know how to create a test case in general, but not one that is associated with an existing bug.

Can someone tell me how to do these things? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any work item that is linked to your Bug is considered a `RelatedLink`. Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.link%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for the available types that derive from `Link` and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8669341/728929) SO-post by @bryanmac.
With the following you should be able to retrieve the type of each related work item of your bug 123456.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;

namespace WorkItemLinksOfAWorkItem
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://TFSURI"));

            var workItemStore = (WorkItemStore)teamProjectCollection.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));

            var workItem = workItemStore.GetWorkItem(123456);
            LinkCollection links = workItem.Links;
            foreach (Link link in links)
            {
                if (!(link is RelatedLink))
                    continue;

                var relLink = link as RelatedLink;
                var relatedWI = workItemStore.GetWorkItem(relLink.RelatedWorkItemId);
                Console.WriteLine(relatedWI.Id+" "+relatedWI.Type.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(I had originally found the base of these sources in [Scrum Dashboard](https://scrumdashboard.codeplex.com/))

In order to generate a new Test Case for your Bug 123456 you could try something like:

```
var workItemTypes = workItemStore.Projects["TeamProjectName"].WorkItemTypes;
var workItem = new WorkItem(workItemTypes["Test Case"]) {Title = "Programmatically constructed via TFS-SDK"};

var relatedLinkToBug = new RelatedLink(123456);
var links = workItem.Links;
links.Add(relatedLinkToBug);

workItem.Save();
```